# Error when working with GradientTape() and jacobian() in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, gradienttape

I am working with GradientTape() and jacobian() in Tensorflow 2.0 in Python.

This code executes fine:

```
x = tf.Variable(2.0, dtype=tf.float32)
with tf.GradientTape() as gT:
    gT.watch(x)
    g = tf.convert_to_tensor([x, 0.0], dtype=tf.float32)
dg = gT.jacobian(g, x)
```

But this code breaks:

```
x = tf.Variable(2.0, dtype=tf.float32)
with tf.GradientTape() as gT:
    gT.watch(x)
    gv = tf.Variable([x, 0.0], dtype=tf.float32)
    g = tf.convert_to_tensor(gv , dtype=tf.float32)
dg = gT.jacobian(g, x)
```

and throws the error:

> InvalidArgumentError:  You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'loop_body/Placeholder' with dtype int32
>        [[node loop_body/Placeholder (defined at ...Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_f_995]
>
> > Traceback (most recent call last) ipython-input-32-686c8a0d6e95 in module
> >           4       gv = tf.Variable([x, 0.0], dtype=tf.float32)
> >           5       g = tf.convert_to_tensor(gv , dtype=tf.float32)
> >     ----> 6      dg = gT.jacobian(g, x)

Why does the first code work, but the second code doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is pretty simple,

In the first example, you got

`g = tf.convert_to_tensor([x, 0.0], dtype=tf.float32)`

and compute `dg/dx` and `g` has a direct relationship with `x` and works fine.

But in the second example,

```
gv = tf.Variable([x, 0.0], dtype=tf.float32)
g = tf.convert_to_tensor(gv , dtype=tf.float32)
```

There's no connection between `g` and `x` any more, because when you call,

`gv = tf.Variable([x, 0.0], dtype=tf.float32)`

it just copies the values from `x` and doesn't carry a reference to `x`, so you cannot get derivative `dg/dx`. But if you try `dg/d(gv)` it'll work.

**PS**: I didn't get an error though (for your second example). I just got `None`.